# crystal build with release option error

Tags: crystal-lang

Very simple code(fibonachi sequence):

```
root@u2:~# crystal build fibo.cr
root@u2:~# crystal build fibo.cr --release
crystal: /var/cache/omnibus/src/llvm/llvm-3.8.1.src/lib/CodeGen/LexicalScopes.cpp:160: llvm::LexicalScope* llvm::LexicalScopes::getOrCreateRegularScope(const llvm::DILocalScope*): Assertion `cast<DISubprogram>(Scope)->describes(MF->getFunction())' failed.
/usr/bin/crystal: строка 102:  1929 Аварийный останов         (стек памяти сброшен на диск) "$INSTALL_DIR/embedded/bin/crystal" "$@"
```

Is it something wrong with optimizer?
I run this on VM with 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit [a known bug](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4719) we're trying to fix.

The workaround that's proven to work is to use `--release` always with `--no-debug`, or to avoid it at all.